# Whats the point of this LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 reference?

Tags: 3d, directx, directx9

I'm going through the [DirectX 9 MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Which lead me to something rather peculiar, do you need a class reference in DirectX 9?

Can someone tell me what the point of the class reference:

`LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9  d3ddev;`

I don't see anything using it.

Also maybe point me in the direction to some decent documentation  for DirectX 9 that explains this stuff like this:

```
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice = NULL;

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp; 

ZeroMemory( &d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp) );
d3dpp.Windowed   = TRUE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY;
```

in little bit more detail then slapping some code in your face with no actual description of what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

`LPDIRECT3DDEVICE` is a "long pointer" (common Win32 prefix LP) to a `Direct3D9Device`.

This is a handle to the driver context.  It is what is responsible for issuing commands to the driver.  There may be multiple drivers (if you have multiple cards), or an app may have multiple handles (if it needs to completely separate data), so the context is not implicit.  This handle is also part of the COM interface to Direct3D, which requires a COM object instance.

`D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` is a set of data that informs Direct3D how to copy the back buffer and how the actual window is displayed.  The lines you reference set the Direct3D display to windowed mode, which has some different characters to full-screen mode (in windowed mode, Direct3D cannot acquire ownership of the entire screen, so it must "play nice" with other apps).  It sets the "swap effect" to copy, which means that the back-buffer is copied onto the front buffer whenever you *present* the backbuffer (usually at the end of each frame).

The call to `ZeroMemory` sets all the fields of `d3dpp` to 0, which are generally good default values.  Remember that variables of POD (plain old data, like most primitive types and any C-style structs) are uninitialized when declare.  You could manually set every field of `d3dpp`, but you'd just be setting most of them to 0 anyway, so the call to `ZeroMemory` is just more convenient.  It's not bad practice in general for your own code since it helps protect against unintentional use of uninitialized fields if you add a new field to a struct.  I tend to use `memset` instead for portability.

Comment: So Direct3D9Device It's a context just like in OpenGL with the WGLContext.?

Comment: Roughly, yes, they both represent device contexts; even though `WGLContext` is exclusive to WGL, an extension of OpenGL.

Comment: Shotgun Ninja: question in the msdn documentation there is this parameter that is set like       Device.m_DevType where is Device defined and its members ?

Comment: `CheckDeviceType` documents that parameter is a `D3DDEVTYPE` which you usually want to set to `D3DDEVTYPE_HAL` (hardware accelerated).  `Device` was for exposition in that example.

Comment: I suspect the last sentence in the answer doesn't say what you meant it to.

Comment: @Adam: instead, only one missing letter and a transposed one, though. :)